# Do plugin auto-updates also run for a lower version?

Tags: plugin-development, automatic-updates

We are planning to upload a new major version of our plugin to the WordPress Plugins Directory.

As part of our contingency planning, we wanted to understand how *rolling back* to the old version might affect existing users. In other words, what will happen if we upload version `2.x.x` - and then re-upload version `1.x.x`?

**Specific use cases:**

a) User updated to `2.x.x` **via auto-updates** (and has auto-updates turned on). If we upload `1.x.x`, will they auto-update to that version?

b)  User installed plugin `2.x.x` **manually** (using a ZIP file), and has auto-updates turned on. If we upload `1.x.x`, will they auto-update to that version?

Comment: If auto update is turned on and you upload an earlier version of a plugin hosted on wordpress.org then this will be updated to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates are very basic and simply check the version number. Anybody on 2.x.x of your plugin will not see an update available because it the latest version will appear to be an older version. How the plugin was originally installed has no impact on this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. In other words, the only way to trigger an auto-update is by uploading a _higher_ version number? i.e. you cannot roll users back to a previous version?

Comment: For it to appear as an update, yes. Whether the plugin repository has an alternate method of rolling users back is something you should ask them.